# How to convert list to cycles?

Tags: list-manipulation

My code below returns the list: `{1, 3, 2, 4}`.  I want the disjoint cycle representation of this permutation. In other words, I want: `Cycles[{{2, 3}}]`.  I tried `PermutationCycles[list]`, but this does not work.

```
T = {{0, 1}, {1, 0}};
list = Map[MatrixForm, Map[Mod[T.#, 2] &, Tuples[{0, 1}, 2]] /. Table[Tuples[{0, 1}, 2][[i]] -> i, {i, 1, 4}]
```

Comment: remove the `MatrixForm` wrapper. (that is, use `list2 = Map[Mod[T.#, 2] &, Tuples[{0, 1}, 2]] /.  Table[Tuples[{0, 1}, 2][[i]] -> i, {i, 1, 4}]; PermutationCycles @ list2`)

Comment: or more directly, `PermutationCycles@Ordering@Mod[Tuples[{0, 1}, 2].T, 2]`?

Comment: PermutationCycles[{1, 3, 2, 4}] will do the job.